# Phillips hue color change during set time

Tags: c#, philips-hue

I have 3 led strips, and I want the to change color during a set time period (For example 8:00-9:30). The phillips hue app does not allow for this, so I decided I want to program it.

I have already got it setup in visual studio, but I need to create a method for changing color during a set time period? Any idea on how I am supposed to tackle this? There are not many guides/tutorials that shows this.

```
public void ColorChangeLED()
{

}
```

I haven't really done anything yet since I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Before implementing anything with code, I suggest you familiarize yourself with the Philips Hue API via the [openhue-api](https://github.com/openhue/openhue-api?tab=readme-ov-file#usage) project.

As a first step, you could simply import the API into Postman and understand how to control the lights.

Then, you could quickly implement this in your C# project and even [generate the code from the OpenAPI specification](https://kaylumah.nl/2023/04/14/csharp-client-for-openapi-revistted.html).